# Implementing filter on ag-grid serverSide rowModelType

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I implemented ag-grid with server side rowModelType.

Above the grid i have an input textbox which will filter the grid.
For example if user typed "abc" in the grid i should go to the server with "searchString=abc" in the url.

I need to redraw the grid with new data from server.
Before the rowModelType change i used the "setData" method in the api but after the change the method not exists in the grid api.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to *redraw* the grid, there are several different refresh mechanism in`gridApi` you could try, depending on your chosen `rowModel`.

Here's what I normally do with a serverSide rowModel:
`gridApi.purgeServerSideCache()`

---

#### Other types for completeness:

#### RowModel: Infinite

`gridApi.refreshInfiniteCache()`

`gridApi.purgeInfiniteCache()`

#### RowModel: ClientSide

`gridApi.refreshClientSideRowModel()`

Further details can be found [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/), they are a bit scattered though.

---

However, your question can be interpreted in two ways, and I'm not sure if you really want to redraw your grid.

Instead, when using the `serverSide` rowModel you should have a `onGridReady()` callback somwhere in your codebase, in which you setup your enterprise request handler: `gridApi.setServerSideDatasource({getRows: myGetRowsHandler})`.
Your custom `myGetRowsHandler` handler should be called on every *filter change*, *sorting*, *grouping* or *paging* event and gets a `parameters` object passed into it.

When your request completes, you need to invoke the `parameters.successCallback()` which looks like this in TypeScript: `successCallback(rowsThisPage: any[], lastRow: number): void`

Comment: Thanks. i used gridApi.setServerSideDatasource and pass the filters